# How can i create a LineString geoJson with data from data base?

Tags: php, json, postgresql, geojson

ok, so I know how to convert data from php to geojson format into point types but i dont understand how can I make this into a lineString type here is the code, so the question is how can i get the coordinates data into one array :

```
    include('testcon.php');


   $query=pg_query($connect,"SELECT number, state, data, latitude, 
       long "
        . "FROM schema.table "
        . "WHERE number = '63' AND "
        . "data BETWEEN '2018-12-01 00:00:00' and '2018-12-01 23:59:59' 
     limit 200 ");
    # Try query or error


  # Build GeoJSON feature collection array
        $geojson = array(
      'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
         'features'  => array()
        );
         # Loop through rows to build feature arrays
          while($row = pg_fetch_array($query)) {
$feature = array(
    'type' => 'Feature', 
    'geometry' => array(
        'type' => 'Point',
        # Pass Longitude and Latitude Columns here
        'coordinates' => array($row['long'], $row['lat'])
    ),
    # Pass other attribute columns here
    'properties' => array(
        'indicativ' => $row['number'],
        'stare' => $row['state'],

        )
    );
    # Add feature arrays to feature collection array
    array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
   }
 header('Content-type: application/json');
   echo json_encode($geojson, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
   $conn = NULL;

      ?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it

```
   $pointlist=array();
        while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($query)) {
       $pointlist[]=array($row['long'], $row['lat']);

     };
             # Build GeoJSON feature collection array
           $geojson = array(
             'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
             'features'  => array(
            #);
             #$feature = array(

    'type' => 'Feature', 
    'geometry' => array(
        'type'=> 'LineString',
        'coordinates'=> $pointlist
        )));
```

i create an empty array and then looped through all the data from lat and long columns and than in coordinates i got the variabel